# Zoho Inventory API json

Tags: api, postman, zoho

When I run a test GET call in postman I get back the following json

```
"code": 0,
    "message": "success",
    "packages": [
        {
            "package_id": "1041677000009727045",
            "salesorder_id": "1041677000009727003",
            "shipment_id": "",
            "customer_id": "1041677000007872931",
            "customer_name": "TEST",
            "status": "not_shipped",
            "package_number": "PKG-00005",
            "tracking_number": "",
            "is_tracking_enabled": false,
            "shipping_charge": 0,
            "date": "2019-02-26",
            "quantity": 1,
            "salesorder_number": "SO-00023",
            "created_time": "2019-02-26T16:13:11-0500",
            "delivery_method": "",
            "last_modified_time": "2019-02-26T16:13:11-0500",
            "shipment_date": "",
            "is_carrier_shipment": false,
            "associated_packages_count": 0
        },
         ],
    "page_context": {
        "page": 1,
        "per_page": 200,
        "has_more_page": false,
        "report_name": "zom.common.Packages",
        "applied_filter": "Status.All",
        "custom_fields": [],
        "sort_column": "created_time",
        "sort_order": "D"
    }
}
```

My issue is that the API request does not show `line_items` as shown in the documentation (https://www.zoho.com/inventory/api/v1/#Packages).

Does anyone know if the line_items exist but it just can't be seen as a json (e.g. I can update them but postman just cant view them?)

Had a support ticket in with Zoho but they haven't replied.

Comment: Zoho never replied, ticket was assigned and overdue, I think they are stumped

Answer (score 0):

Try retrieving one package with the postman version of:
`curl https://inventory.zoho.com/api/v1/packages/{package_id}`

It should display the `line_items` per this documentation:
https://www.zoho.com/inventory/api/v1/packages/#retrieving-a-package